# Failed to resolve module specifier "dotenv". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, node.js, dotenv

I'm trying to store my API key in the .env file and get the key in news.js, but I got the error 'Failed to resolve module specifier "dotenv". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".'

```
/*news.js*/
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY
console.log(key);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=covid&apiKey=${key}`)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    renderArticles(data)
  })
})

/*news.html*/
 <script type="module" src="js/news.js"></script>

/*index.js*/
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config();
const apiKey = process.env.API_KEY
console.log(apiKey);
```

I added "type": "module" on package.json as well.

Comment: naive question, did you did the install of the module, like in "npm install dotenv"

Comment: also, there is a well explained documentation here on how to setup the module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: I'm pretty sure dotenv is for serverside only. Especially since it would be beside the point if your ENV secrets were importable on the client

Comment: That was my lack of knowledge that dotenv is for serverside only. I solved this problem, thank you so much